# EPPlus 5 doesn't auto-increments formulas correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

I was applying a formula to a range using `EPPlus 4`, and it worked perfectly, like this:

```
sheet.cells[FromRow,FromCol,ToRow,ToCol].formula=myformula
```

the excel formula itself is `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B2,NEW!A:A,1,0)),"delete","")`, `EPPlus 4`  auto-incremented the formula on the other rows perfectly, incrementing only the "B2" to B3,B4,B5...

The problem started when i had to upgrade to `EPPlus 5`, now when trying to do the same thing it auto-increments in the wrong way, it stills increments the "B2" normally but now it tries to increment the "NEW!A:A" as well, and fails miserably, it turns like this `NEW!A2:#REF!`,`NEW!A3:#REF!`,`NEW!A4:#REF!`.

How can i get it working like it used to on `EPPlus 4`?, i already tried to put `NEW!$A:$A` on the formula, and i can't go back to `version 4` as it doesn't support IF formulas on the .Calculate() function.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-increment formulas work in EPPlus 6.2.2. Note that if you have top-row formula already, than you need to refill her cell too. Like this:

```
var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
var formula = sheet.Cells[1, 5].Formula;
sheet.Cells[1, 5, 30, 5].Formula = formula;
```